# Align equations over 2 columns

Tags: equations, aligned

I would like to write equation in Latex of the same form as the figure below:
[image]

I want Eq. 3 centered to Eq. 1 and Eq. 2.

The best I have done is this:
[image]

With this code:

```
\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
        \text{Eq. 1}& \\
        & & \text{Eq. 3}\\
        &\text{Eq. 2}& \\ 
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

Do you have a better way to do it? I don't want the space between Eq 1 and Eq. 2.

Thanks ! ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Why not move your Eq. 3 out of the aligned environment ?

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
    \text{Eq. 1} \\
    \text{Eq. 2} \\
  \end{aligned}
  \qquad \text{Eq. 3}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It works well ! ;)

Answer (score 3):

Something like this might do it.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  \begin{aligned}
    \boxed{A}
    \\
    \boxed{B}
  \end{aligned}
  &&&
     \begin{aligned}
      \boxed{C}
    \end{aligned}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

If you don't need alignments inside the three blocks, you can use `gathered` instead of `aligned`.

The `&&&` is a trick to make `align*` separate the two blocks.